# TextToSpeech is giving error service isn't started

Tags: android

I am using text to speech in my project but it is throwing this error.
Can anyone tell please what i must do so that it work...

Code....

```
public class CallerService extends Service implements
    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

String number;

private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

}

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    number = intent.getStringExtra("phnumber");

    fetchContacts();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) 
     {
             tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
     } 
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();

}

public void fetchContacts() {

    String phoneNumber = null;

    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;

    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;

    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String contact_id = cursor
                    .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));

                    boolean a = PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number,
                            phoneNumber);
                    if (a) {

                        String contname = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                        if (!contname.equals(null)) {

                            Log.i("Contact Name: ", contname);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    contname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            tts.speak(contname, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                                    null);

                        }
                    }


                }

                phoneCursor.close();

            }


        }

    }

}

}
```

Logcat is...

```
04-07 12:26:59.998: I/State(5948): Call is Ringing
04-07 12:27:00.028: I/TextToSpeech.java(5948): initTts() successfully bound to service
04-07 12:27:01.038: D/dalvikvm(5948): GC_EXPLICIT freed 83K, 45% free 3123K/5639K, `external 743K/1036K, paused 54ms
04-07 12:27:02.158: I/Contact Name:(5948): kd arjit
04-07 12:27:02.168: I/TextToSpeech.java - speak(5948): speak text of length 8
04-07 12:27:02.168: E/TextToSpeech.java - speak(5948): service isn't started
04-07 12:27:02.298: D/dalvikvm(5948): GC_CONCURRENT freed 375K, 48% free 3142K/5959K, external 758K/1036K, paused 2ms+4ms
04-07 12:27:02.308: W/CursorWrapperInner(5948): Cursor finalized without prior close()
04-07 12:27:09.708: I/State(5948): Idle State`
```

Comment: can you please post your code? are you able to compile or is this error even before compile. if error is when running the app - paste LogCat message please

Comment: Please post log-cat along with code

Comment: can you try google translate?

Comment: if you think , I can answer how can you do text to speech with google

Comment: Please tell i will be thankful to you